# Human readable name instead of ClientID for 2-legged OAuth Google Drive upload?

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api

i am using 2-legged OAuth 2.0 to upload files to Google Drive. The owner of these files is shown as the ClientID i created in the Google Developer Console. Is it possible to either rename the ClientID to something more human readable or to use some kind of alias when uploading to Google Drive?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rename or edit the client ID. In Google API console, you can only edit the Client ID settings like: Redirect URIs and JavaScript origins but not the client ID itself.

Client Id(unique client identifier) is a unique value which is a randomly generated number. You can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingoauth2) for more information.

https://developer.concur.com/oauth-20/oauth-20-overview#consumer_key

Hope that helps!

Comment: To avoid this problem i created a virtual user to which i transfer the file ownership so that the Google Drive interface doesn't look so broken.